# Multilingual full-text search with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search, multilingual

The user input can be in English or Italian. The data are both in English and (mostly) Italian. The following is my query (seems working), my question is if this is the correct way to handle an unknown language input. (In the example the user type the word 'wine'):

```
    SELECT id, name
    FROM (
        SELECT p.id, p.name,
                to_tsvector('italian', p.name) || --some data are only in italian
                to_tsvector('italian', cat.category) || 
                to_tsvector((CASE WHEN de.language = 'ITA' THEN 'italian' ELSE 'english' END)::regconfig, coalesce(string_agg(de.descr, ' '))) as document 

        FROM myschema.product p
        INNER JOIN myschema.disc d ON d.id_disc = p.id_disc
        INNER JOIN myschema.disc_city dc ON dc.id_disc = d.id_disc
        INNER JOIN myschema.city c ON c.id_city = dc.id_city 
        INNER JOIN myschema.category cat ON cat.id_category = d.id_category
        INNER JOIN myschema.product_desc pd ON pd.id = p.id --One p.id to Many pd.id, a product can have multiple descriptions
        INNER JOIN myschema.descr de ON de.id_descr = pd.id_descr
        GROUP BY p.id, p.name, cat.category, de.language    
    ) p_search
--handling input 'wine' of unknown language (could be too the italian 'vino')
    WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('italian', 'wine') OR
        p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('english', 'wine');
    GROUP BY id, name
```

Answer (score 1):

With PostgreSQL you can create your own dictionary:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.wine_dict (
TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
STOPWORDS = wine
);
```

the file wine.stop contain the stopword of your dictionary:

```
wine
merlot 
carmenere
...
```

this file must be locate in  $SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/wine.stop
use  pg_config --sharedir to find $SHAREDIR

and then create SEARCH DICTIONARY  :

```
 CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.wine_dict (
 TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
 STOPWORDS = wine
 );

 CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION wine_dict(parser = default);

 ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION wine_dict
 ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart,
 word, hword, hword_part
 WITH wine_dict;

SELECT to_tsvector('wine_dict', 'The wine is good');

result: 
'good':4 'is':3 'the':1
```

Comment: So the best solution is to merge italian and english dictionary and using this in the where condition (alias the only part with unknown language)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'simple' dictionary, test this:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'The wine is good');
SELECT to_tsvector('italian', 'The wine is good');
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'The wine is good');

SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'Il vino è buono');
SELECT to_tsvector('italian', 'Il vino è buono');
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'Il vino è buono');
```

Comment: I would like to stem my input word "wine", using the "simple" dictionary the search results aren't good.

Comment: you can create your own dictionary with customize stopword (wine for example) see the doc :



 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY 

and my next answer...